# Can't copy file as root in Linux?

Tags: linux

I am using Cent-OS and I am trying to copy a file. I su to root first, then I execute:

```
cp test.txt /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/management
```

But I get an input/output error. Why can't I copy this file as root? Is there something that can lock a folder in Linux so root can't change it?

Comment: do you have enough space?

Comment: Yes, the file is empty and I have several GB of space.

Answer (score 1):

`root` is a concept to get around the system's permissions.

IO error is a more physical problem that could be of a much more varied nature. Common examples included faulty media, unreadable CDs, lost connection, and so on.

Comment: Hmmm... Well, I am copying the file from the desktop to a location on the local disk. Could that mean something is corrupt on the local drive?